# Messaging approach for mobile consumers

Tags: android, jms, apache-kafka, messaging

I have thousands of mobile devices in my system. They are connected to my central server. I need to have a mechanism to update them based on some event which specific devices are following (notify by topic). Let's say I have chats on server and mobile user can follow any chat and want to efficiently recieve notifications of new messages in a chat. The primary mobile platform is Android.

I'm thinking to use messaging using topic (per chat): Kafka or RabbitMQ.
Please give advice what is good for mobile consumers.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka and RabbitMQ are quite different approaches. Kafka is a log storing system (i.e. an ordered sequence of messages) and RabbitMQ is just queueing and routing.

I am designing a event sourcing system. I use:

1. kafka in the backend
2. RabbitMQ (or other platforms such as XMPP) to connect clients

RabbitMQ scales well on thousands of queues and allows the client to define private queues (unnamed, temporal, single consumer, exclude) which are needed for RPC and simple security. Clients usually need to execute specific functions on the cluster or only read a filtered set of events (not all events) due to their limition in bandwidth. Theorically, kafka could be used but there are several challenges right now (i.e. topic limits, exclusive queues, autodelete, etc).

Kafka (+samza) is a very good tool for event sourcing (i.e. navigating through the history of messages) and real time stream processing (automatical replay, restarting processes, etc). Scaling is not a need as it is integration, high disponibility and recovering.

Answer (score 0):

MQTT seems a good solution to your problem. Basically it is small, lightweight, efficient, and very good for battery life (see [MQTT used by facebook messenger](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger)).

Moreover MQTT is an OASIS standard and there are many compatible brokers, some of them allow the management of several million simultaneous connections (for example JoramMQ is [used in very scalable applications](http://www.scalagent.com/internet-des-objets?id_article=827)).